# I want to store an array values in a hidden input field

Tags: javascript

```js
const arr = [];
document.querySelector("#lengthParams").setAttribute('value',arr);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="lengthParams" name="lengthParams" value="">
```

the array is not null -> (3) ["0.00", "15.00", "15.00"]
phpstorm suggests "Argument type any[] is not assignable to parameter type string".
can anyone please suggest what changes should I make?

Comment: Attribute values are strings. Arrays are not strings. Perhaps you want to [_join_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array into a string or even [_stringify_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it as JSON

Comment: you have to encode your PHP array into JSON. by using json_encode($you_array). and then hold into input and once you need it. you can again decode it later in an array using php.

Comment: @VishalVishwakarma there is no PHP in this question

Comment: @Phil const JosonData = JSON.stringify(arr );
you can use this also if you want to do the same in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr=['12','34','45']
arr=arr.toString()
document.querySelector("#lengthParams").setAttribute('value',arr);
```

You can make use of this